# @AuthenticationPrincipal object return session value

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-test, spring-security-oauth2

@AuthenticationPrincipal object return previous value which was stored in session.

Spring boot + spring security oauth REST Server. https://github.com/legshort/spring-boot-sample

These two REST methos are in controller. Problem is that a last argument, userDetailsImpl at deleteUser() is same value as userDetailsImpl at updateUser() when I run test code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/users/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl,
        @Valid @RequestBody UserUpdateForm userUpdateForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
    logger.info("UserUpdate: " + userUpdateForm);

    User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(userUpdateForm
            .createUser(userId));

    return new ResponseEntity(updatedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/users/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity deleteUser(@PathVariable Long userId,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl) {
    logger.info("UserDelete: " + userId);

    User requestedUser = new User(userId);
    userService.deleteUser(requestedUser);

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Below is controller test code

I don't know how but second request which is testDeleteUser() has session value and it's a same user that used previous test. so even thought at the beginning of deleteUser() validate access token and load right new user but somehow real value at userDetailsImpl has wrong user that created at the beginning of testUpdateUser().

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(filterChainProxy).build();
}

@Test
public void testUpdateUser() throws Exception {
    User savedUser = signUpUser();

    // @formatter:off
    mockMvc.perform(
            put("/users/" + savedUser.getId())
            .header(HeaderUtil.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthorizationWithAccessToken())
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(UserUpdateFormFactory.newInstance())))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(greaterThan(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ZERO))))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(equalTo(StringUtil.NEW + UserFactory.NAME))));
    // @formatter:on
}

@Test
public void testDeleteUser() throws Exception {
    User savedUser = signUpUser();
    String authorization = getAuthorizationWithAccessToken();

    // @formatter:off
    mockMvc.perform(
            delete("/users/" + savedUser.getId())
            .header(HeaderUtil.AUTHORIZATION, authorization)
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
    // @formatter:on
}
```

This is UserDetailService implementation, when it comes to loadUserByUserName() to validate access token, it loads proper user from database and return new user that just created at the beginning of every test method(signUpUser()).

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User requestedUser = new User();
        requestedUser.setEmail(email);

        User savedUser = userService.findByEmail(requestedUser);

        return new UserDetailsImpl(savedUser);
    }
}
```

I tried to disable session which I failed, seems fine with configuration and test code to me.
Is there any good practical example for spring-security-oauth?

---

**UPDATED**

1. As far as I understand about mockMvc is, it clears all settings and it creates pretty much new mock server every time with setUp() method. Therefore, access token store should be cleared every time but somehow token store maintains authenticated tokens.
2. Asking access token requested with "/oauth/token" as ommited during the test, below is how InMemoryTokenStore was called.

---

**Testing Process Log**

1. testUpdateUser() -> POST: /oauth/token -> store token
   token: 50b10897-9e15-4859-aeb0-43d0802ba42c
   user: id=2
2. testUpdateUser() -> PUT: /users/2 -> read token
   token: 50b10897-9e15-4859-aeb0-43d0802ba42c
   user: id=2
3. testUpdateUserWithWrongUserId() -> GET: /oauth/token -> store token
   token: 50b10897-9e15-4859-aeb0-43d0802ba42c -> already existed in token
   user: id=2 -> id=4: user was updated with new one
4. testUpdateUserWithWrongUserId() -> PUT: /users/0 -> read token
   token: 50b10897-9e15-4859-aeb0-43d0802ba42c
   user: id=2
5. testDeleteUser() -> GET: /oauth/token -> did not store token, supposed to store token
6. testDeleteUser() -> DELETE: /users/5 -> read token
   token: 50b10897-9e15-4859-aeb0-43d0802ba42c
   user: id=2 -> user was supposed to id=5 which was created with userSignUp()

---

**Questions**
How to clear InMemoryTokenStore every test method with mockMvc?

Comment: You use only one instance of wac (WebApplicationContext) so principal is stored there between two tests executions. Why just not to set up principal explicitly in each test like `delete("/users/" + savedUser.getId()).principal(null)` ??

Comment: AuthenticationPrincipal is intended to be the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(), so this is expected behavior. I guess I'm struggling to figure out what you want your code to do.

Comment: @RobWinch thanks for your comment. I want to test every method with clean status so that I wish there is no session or principal every test method and what I understand is every test method should be clean in order to prevent any other strange behavior.

Comment: @gsolecki thanks your guide, however, principal() does not take null and kind of hard to find out how I should call principal(), could you give me more specific example please?

Comment: @RobWinch I think spring-security-oauth should depend only accessToken in request header on every test. And please let me guide to proper test if I am doing wrong with test code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // ignore spring security session
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
```

Comment: Perhaps explaining where you have to put this code and explain why it should solve the problem would make your answer better quality.

Comment: You will need to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and place http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER) in there. This comes from the argument that rest services are stateless and a session holds state but because that state held in session is not related to the data but rather session is metadata who cares.